# Unable to create a TDS project in VS 2015/2017

Tags: tds

Installed TDS CLASSIC 5.7 on local machine for VS 2017 and VS 2015. I've tried to create TDS project.

It is giving error as shown below:

> *.scproj cannot be opened because its project type (.scproj) is not
>   supported by this version of the application"

[image]

Could you suggest where is the problem?

Comment: In which version of VS have you created TDS package 2015 or 2017? In which version are you trying to open it? It is pretty strange that the path contains `Temp` folder for current user. Could you mode the whole solution somewhere else and not trying to open it from zip directly?

Comment: Put also content of scproj file to your question

Comment: I've tried with both versions 2015 professional and 2017 Community versions. I'm trying to create a new TDS project.

Comment: I've tried with both versions of Visual Studio (2015 Professional and 2017 community). I'm trying to create a new TDS project. While installing I did not specify any license details, still it allowed me to install. This might be causing the issue. If I want to use TDS classic free trail, I need to register and get the key for 30 days. I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community edition of Visual Studio is not supported as far as I remember due to constrains on VS side.

To fix your issues you should follow below instructions.

**For VS2015:**

- Obtain trial license of TDS Classic -> https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/TDS-Classic/Free-Trial
- Reinstall TDS for VS 2015, you can find specific installation files in downloaded installation package and use your trial license during installation
- You can also try to just reentering license information -> https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter2.html#updating-the-tds-classic-license
- Run VS prior to opening scproj file and check whether license is valid by going to Help > View TDS Classic License. You should see here whether license is valid and also when it expires.

**For VS2017:**

- Reinstall VS 2017 to at least Professional edition
- Follow all steps for VS2015

Answer (score 0):

Normally such issue could be resolved by installing TDS again. Also check the location of the project template.

Check the system requirement section. https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter2.html#system-requirements. Try with this.

Which version of visual studio you are using? Is it ultimate or community?

Also same issue mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526317/cannot-open-scproj-project-in-visual-studio
This is for vs 2010.